# All combinations across multiple lists

Tags: python

Given a multidimensional list (a list of lists) I would like to get all possible combinations of the sub lists items.

For example an input of:

```
my_list = [
    ['a', 'b'], ['1', '2'], ['@', '&']
]
```

Would result in:

```
result = [
['a'],
['b'],
['1'],
['2'],
['@'],
['&'],
['a', '1'],
['a', '2'],
['a', '@'],
['a', '&']
['b', '1'],
['b', '2'],
['b', '@'],
['b', '&'],
['a', '1', '@'],
['a', '1', '&'],
['a', '2', '@'],
['a', '2', '&'],
...]
```

I tried using itertools.product(*list) but that results in a combination of all items without the smaller sets of combinations. It seems that itertools.combinations, itertools.permutations, etc don't quite give what I am looking for.

Is there a quick way of doing this?

Comment: Should, for example, `['1', '@']` appear in the output?

Comment: What is unclear? I'm trying to get a combination of all the items of multiple lists. I'm not being intentionally unclear. If you help explain what you don't understand I'll try to be more articulate.

Comment: "a combination of all the items of multiple lists" is still extremely vague. You have some mental model of how the items are to be drawn and what should or shouldn't count as a valid combination, which seems obvious to you, but isn't obvious. You need to actually say it explicitly.

Comment: I want every possible combination excluding combinations of items in the same lists. For example itertools.combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD is a problem because it's combining items in the same list. I thought that was made clear by looking at the expected output and is why I provided it. I'm looking for that functionality but between multiple lists and for all lengths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case you first iterate over all possible lengths. For each length you pick all possible combinations of lists, and for each of these combinations you use `itertools.product`:

```
def weird_product(*data):
    for i in range(1,len(data)+1):
        for subdata in itertools.combinations(data,i):
            for elem in itertools.product(*subdata):
                yield elem
```

This generates:

```
>>> list(weird_product(*data))
[('a',), ('b',), ('1',), ('2',), ('@',), ('&',), ('a', '1'), ('a', '2'), ('b', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('a', '@'), ('a', '&'), ('b', '@'), ('b', '&'), ('1', '@'), ('1', '&'), ('2', '@'), ('2', '&'), ('a', '1', '@'), ('a', '1', '&'), ('a', '2', '@'), ('a', '2', '&'), ('b', '1', '@'), ('b', '1', '&'), ('b', '2', '@'), ('b', '2', '&')]
```

or more elegantly formatted:

```
>>> list(weird_product(*data))
[('a',),
 ('b',),
 ('1',),
 ('2',),
 ('@',),
 ('&',),
 ('a', '1'),
 ('a', '2'),
 ('b', '1'),
 ('b', '2'),
 ('a', '@'),
 ('a', '&'),
 ('b', '@'),
 ('b', '&'),
 ('1', '@'),
 ('1', '&'),
 ('2', '@'),
 ('2', '&'),
 ('a', '1', '@'),
 ('a', '1', '&'),
 ('a', '2', '@'),
 ('a', '2', '&'),
 ('b', '1', '@'),
 ('b', '1', '&'),
 ('b', '2', '@'),
 ('b', '2', '&')]
```